# Telit GSM/GPRS modem HE910, AT#HTTPRCV giving ERROR

Tags: embedded, gsm, modem, gprs

I am using Telit modem HE910 in my project :
AT+CGMR
12.00.004

OK

I am implementing firmware update over the air for which I need to download my firmware from a http link. To implement this I used AT#SD command to dial a socket and then used http to download the file in a chunk of 512 bytes at a time because of my UART buffer limitation. This is is working fine but taking too long to download the file.

Now I am trying other method to download using Telit HTTP client using the AT commands:

AT#HTTPCFG=0,"XXXXXXX",80,0,,,0,120,1

AT#HTTPQRY=0,0,"/ud/myfirmware.hex"
OK

## HTTPRING: 0,200,"application/octet-stream",2083

Now if I run AT#HTTPRCV=0 I am getting my firmware data as:

AT#HTTPRCV=0
<<<:10000000E0C500002FC600002DC600002BC6000072
:1000100029C6000027C6000025C6000023C6000030
:1000200021C600001FC600001DC600001BC6000040...............

But this is big for my UART buffer.
As per the data sheet I can use AT#HTTPRCV command to download part wise but I when I execute the command like below I get ERROR:

AT#HTTPRCV=0,64
+CME ERROR: 4

as per the datasheet:
Description 
AT$HTTPRCV AT command is used to receive HTTP data from remote server.

AT#HTTPRCV=[,] --  - Max number of bytes to read at a time Range:0,64-1500 (default is 0 which means infinite size)

Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with a Telit UL865-EUD, running 12.00.614. It doesn't seem like the firmware supports the configuration as explained in the manual (CME ERROR 4 means operation not supported).

If you try AT#HTTPCFG=?, you'll see the parameters reported don't include the pktsize variable described in the AT commands manual either.

The best you can do with HTTPRCV is work with the data as it comes from the Telit's rcv buffer, i.e. in <= 300 byte size chunks.